# how to get rid of blurred and overlaping 3d shapes in javafx

Tags: java, javafx

I actually wanted to build a 2x2 rubiks cube. As the Box class in javafx doesn't provide the feature of building a cube with different colours on different faces, I chose to build the cubes using RectangleBuilder to build rectangles with different colours and then applied transformations to build the cubes. But while testing the code I saw that the entire display was coming in a broken manner with the edges overlapping as shown in the picture.[image: Here's the snap] Here is my source code:

```
package helloworld;


import javafx.scene.transform.Rotate;
import javafx.scene.PerspectiveCamera;
import javafx.scene.transform.Translate;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.animation.Animation;
import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.KeyValue;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.SceneAntialiasing;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.RectangleBuilder;
import javafx.scene.transform.Rotate;
import javafx.util.Duration;


    public class NewFXMain1 extends Application {


    public class Cube extends Group {
    final Rotate rx = new Rotate(0,Rotate.X_AXIS);
    final Rotate ry = new Rotate(0,Rotate.Y_AXIS);
    final Rotate rz = new Rotate(0,Rotate.Z_AXIS);
    public Cube(double size, Color back,Color bottom,Color right,Color left,Color top,Color front, double shade) {
        getTransforms().addAll(rz, ry, rx);
        getChildren().addAll(
            RectangleBuilder.create() // back face
                .width(size).height(size)
                .fill(back.deriveColor(0.0, 1.0, (1 - 0.5*shade), 1.0))
                .translateX(-0.5*size)
                .translateY(-0.5*size)
                .translateZ(0.5*size)
                    .smooth(true)
                    .stroke(Color.BLACK)
                .build(),
            RectangleBuilder.create() // bottom face
                .width(size).height(size)
                .fill(bottom.deriveColor(0.0, 1.0, (1 - 0.4*shade), 1.0))
                .translateX(-0.5*size)
                .translateY(0)
                .rotationAxis(Rotate.X_AXIS)
                .rotate(90)
                    .smooth(true)
                    .stroke(Color.BLACK)
                .build(),
            RectangleBuilder.create() // right face
                .width(size).height(size)
                .fill(right.deriveColor(0.0, 1.0, (1 - 0.3*shade), 1.0))
                .translateX(-1*size)
                .translateY(-0.5*size)
                .rotationAxis(Rotate.Y_AXIS)
                .rotate(90)
                    .smooth(true)
                    .stroke(Color.BLACK)
                .build(),
            RectangleBuilder.create() // left face
                .width(size).height(size)
                .fill(left.deriveColor(0.0, 1.0, (1 - 0.2*shade), 1.0))
                .translateX(0)
                .translateY(-0.5*size)
                .rotationAxis(Rotate.Y_AXIS)
                .rotate(90)
                    .smooth(true)
                    .stroke(Color.BLACK)
                .build(),
            RectangleBuilder.create() // top face
                .width(size).height(size)
                .fill(top.deriveColor(0.0, 1.0, (1 - 0.1*shade), 1.0))
                .translateX(-0.5*size)
                .translateY(-1*size)
                .rotationAxis(Rotate.X_AXIS)
                .rotate(90)
                    .smooth(true)
                    .stroke(Color.BLACK)
                .build(),
            RectangleBuilder.create() // front face
                .width(size).height(size)
                .fill(front)
                .translateX(-0.5*size)
                .translateY(-0.5*size)
                .translateZ(-0.5*size)
                    .smooth(true)
                    .stroke(Color.BLACK)
                .build()
        );
    }
    }



    PerspectiveCamera camera = new PerspectiveCamera(true);
    @Override public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

    Group root = new Group();
    Scene scene=new Scene(root,600,600,true);

    camera.setNearClip(0.00001);
    camera.setFarClip(10000000.0);

    camera.getTransforms().addAll (
            new Rotate(0, Rotate.Y_AXIS),
            new Rotate(0, Rotate.X_AXIS),

            new Translate(0, 0, -1000));
    scene.setCamera(camera);
    Cube c1 = new Cube(50,Color.BLUE.darker(),Color.BLUE.darker(),Color.ORANGE.darker(),Color.BLUE.darker(),Color.BLUE.darker(),Color.RED.darker(),1);
     c1.setTranslateX(100);

    Cube c2 = new Cube(50,Color.GREEN.darker(),Color.GREEN.darker(),Color.GREEN.darker(),Color.YELLOW.darker(),Color.BLUE.darker(),Color.RED.darker(),1);
    c2.setTranslateX(50);

    Cube c3 = new Cube(50,Color.CYAN.brighter(),Color.GREEN.darker(),Color.GREEN.darker(),Color.YELLOW.darker(),Color.BLUE.darker(),Color.RED.darker(),1);
    c3.setTranslateX(50);
    c3.setTranslateZ(50);

    Cube c4 = new Cube(50,Color.CYAN.brighter(),Color.GREEN.darker(),Color.ORANGE.darker(),Color.YELLOW.darker(),Color.BLUE.darker(),Color.RED.darker(),1);
    c4.setTranslateX(100);
    c4.setTranslateZ(50);

    Cube c5 = new Cube(50,Color.BLUE.darker(),Color.GREEN.darker(),Color.ORANGE.darker(),Color.BLUE.darker(),Color.BLUE.darker(),Color.RED.darker(),1);
     c5.setTranslateX(100);
     c5.setTranslateY(50);

    Cube c6 = new Cube(50,Color.GREEN.darker(),Color.GREEN.darker(),Color.GREEN.darker(),Color.YELLOW.darker(),Color.BLUE.darker(),Color.RED.darker(),1);
    c6.setTranslateX(50);
    c6.setTranslateY(50);

    Cube c7 = new Cube(50,Color.CYAN.brighter(),Color.GREEN.darker(),Color.GREEN.darker(),Color.YELLOW.darker(),Color.BLUE.darker(),Color.RED.darker(),1);
    c7.setTranslateX(50);
    c7.setTranslateZ(50);
    c7.setTranslateY(50);

    Cube c8 = new Cube(50,Color.CYAN.brighter(),Color.GREEN.darker(),Color.ORANGE.darker(),Color.YELLOW.darker(),Color.BLUE.darker(),Color.RED.darker(),1);
    c8.setTranslateX(100);
    c8.setTranslateZ(50);
    c8.setTranslateY(50);
    handleMouse(scene,root);
    Group k=new Group(c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6,c7,c8);
    root.getChildren().addAll(k);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) { launch(args); }
    private static final double CONTROL_MULTIPLIER = 0.1;   
    private static final double SHIFT_MULTIPLIER = 10.0;   
    private static final double MOUSE_SPEED = 0.1;    
  private static final double ROTATION_SPEED = 2.0; 
  double mousePosX,mousePosY,mouseOldX,mouseOldY,mouseDeltaX,mouseDeltaY;
  private void handleMouse(Scene scene, final Node root) {


    scene.setOnMousePressed(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
        @Override public void handle(MouseEvent me) {
             mousePosX = me.getSceneX();
             mousePosY = me.getSceneY();
             mouseOldX = me.getSceneX();
             mouseOldY = me.getSceneY();
        }
    });
    scene.setOnMouseDragged(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
        @Override public void handle(MouseEvent me) {
            mouseOldX = mousePosX;
            mouseOldY = mousePosY;
            mousePosX = me.getSceneX();
            mousePosY = me.getSceneY();
            mouseDeltaX = (mousePosX - mouseOldX); 
            mouseDeltaY = (mousePosY - mouseOldY);

           double modifier = 1.0;

           if (me.isControlDown()) {
                modifier = CONTROL_MULTIPLIER;
            } 
            if (me.isShiftDown()) {
                modifier = SHIFT_MULTIPLIER;
            }     
            if (me.isPrimaryButtonDown()) {
                camera.setRotationAxis(Rotate.Y_AXIS);camera.setRotate(camera.getRotate() -
                   mouseDeltaX*modifier*ROTATION_SPEED);  // 
               camera.setRotationAxis(Rotate.X_AXIS);camera.setRotate(camera.getRotate() +
                   mouseDeltaY*modifier*ROTATION_SPEED);  // -

            }
            else if (me.isSecondaryButtonDown()) {
                double z = camera.getTranslateZ();
                double newZ = z + mouseDeltaX*MOUSE_SPEED*modifier;
                camera.setTranslateZ(newZ);
            }

       }
   }); // setOnMouseDragged
 } //handleMouse
}
```

Comment: Could you narrow down the example further? For example, does 1 cube render OK? I'm guessing this is an issue with the order in which the rectangles are rendered.

Comment: The same problem with one cube rendered. The opposite and adjacent faces gets overlapped.

Comment: Is there any alternate way to create the cube in which i will not encounter such problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend that you create a custom mesh for your cube utilising TriangleMesh. This should help...

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19459012/how-to-create-custom-3d-model-in-javafx-8

You should also look at the JDK 8 JavaFX examples (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html), as there are also importers for .obj file format models. It would then be very simple to import a custom cube created in .obj format with separate materials for each face. Or you could just create a simple billboard object with two triangles representing each face of each cube. And simply group 6 of these to form a cube, rather than using the RectangleBuilder approach. The depth buffer will then work correctly with the approach I've detailed here.

Also, http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/8/3d_graphics/shapes_3d.htm

Comment: +1, but I had figured out the problem. The problem was related to my faulty setting of the near and far clips of my perspective camera.